# Windows 10 - Games not starting in 64-bit mode

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit

I'm running Windows 10 (64bit) and I'm not able to start games in 64bit mode. Here is a screenshot of the error I receive when trying to start Assetto Corsa:

[image]

The game starts successfully if I do it in 32bit mode.

I've done some research on this and the usual problem is corrupted video drivers or corrupted Visual C++. I've removed and re-installed my video drivers (nvidia) and I've removed and re-installed all Microsoft Visual C++ instances. Neither of these helped me. I now want to know how I can go about debugging this error to try and get to the root cause. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How are you choosing "64-bit mode" or "32-bit mode"? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Is it ALL games, or just that 9 year old one?

Comment: The game has 2 EXEs: one for 32bit and one for 64bit. The 32bit one works, the 64bit one doesn't any more (I'm not sure exactly when it stopped working)

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/app/244210/discussions/0/1727575977543995731?ctp=5#c3184610318757428985 also suggests reinstalling DirectX that might be available under your Steam install folder at `\ steamapps \ common \ Steamworks Shared \ _CommonRedist, all `

Comment: @Mokubai - this worked for me. Thanks very much!

Comment: BTW, do not put essential info in a comment: "The game has 2 EXEs: one for 32bit and one for 64bit. The 32bit one works, the 64bit one doesn't any more " That belongs in the *question*, which you should edit... and at that point, @Mokubai could make the comment an answer, too.